# Как очистить input и вернуться к нему

Tags: python, файлы, pandas, input

У меня есть код, который запоминает слова, а далее отвечает на это(берёт информацию из файлов).
Вопрос - как мне сделать так, чтобы программа не завершалась, а возвращалась к началу? Тут просто указать Start() не имеет пользы, нужно ещё изменить переменную word, чтобы вновь вписать.

Код далеко не идеальный, но главное - он работает. А вот собственно и он:

```
import pandas as pd

word = input("")

def Start():

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "word": word,
    }, index=[0])

    file = open("Lina.csv", "r", encoding = "utf-8") #input
    filelines = file.readlines()

    #Условие - есть в файле строка или нет
    for fileline in filelines:
        if word in fileline.strip('\n').split(','):
            fileQuestion = open(f"question/{word}.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") #output
            print(fileQuestion.read())
            break
    #Если нету строки
    else:
        df.to_csv("Lina.csv", mode="a", index=False, header=False) #Добавление в pd
        question = input("Как мне на это отвечать? ")
        fileQuestion = open(f"question/{word}.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") #Ответы
        fileQuestion.write(question)
        fileQuestion.close()
Start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто добавь `while True:`

```py
import pandas as pd

while True:

    word = input("")

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "word": word,
    }, index=[0])

    file = open("Lina.csv", "r", encoding = "utf-8") #input
    filelines = file.readlines()

    #Условие - есть в файле строка или нет
    for fileline in filelines:
        if word in fileline.strip('\n').split(','):
            fileQuestion = open(f"question/{word}.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") #output
            print(fileQuestion.read())
            break
    #Если нету строки
    else:
        df.to_csv("Lina.csv", mode="a", index=False, header=False) #Добавление в pd
        question = input("Как мне на это отвечать? ")
        fileQuestion = open(f"question/{word}.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") #Ответы
        fileQuestion.write(question)
        fileQuestion.close()
```